# Get data of each element from a json output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each, extract

I'm trying to get each element data stored in a Json output format. I currently have tried the following

**Load individual Json data**

```
function loadFlowchart() {
    var flowChartJson = $('#jsonOutput').val();

    var objFromJson = JSON.parse(flowChartJson);
    var node = objFromJson.node;
    $.each(node, function (index, element) {
        var id = element.id;
        var classes = element.class;
        var positionTop = element.position.top
        alert("Id of element parsed: " + id + "\nclass: " + classes 
        + "\npositionTop: " + positionTop);
    });
}
```

**Method that creates the Json Output**

```
function saveFlowchart(){
    var node = [];
    var matches = [];
    var totalElementCount=0;
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++)
    {
        matches.push(searchEles[i]);
        var idOfEl = searchEles[i].id;
        totalElementCount=idOfEl;

        if(searchEles[i].id !=null || searchEles[i].id !="")
        {
            var $element = $("#" + searchEles[i].id);
            var dropElem = $("#" + searchEles[i].id).attr('class');

            var position = $element.position();

            var elId = parseInt(idOfEl);

            if (dropElem=="streamdrop ui-draggable")
            {
                position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
                position.right = position.left + $element.width();

                node.push({
                    id: idOfEl,
                    class: dropElem,
                    position:
                    {
                        top: position.top,
                        left: position.left,
                        bottom: position.bottom,
                        right: position.right
                    }
                });

                for (var count = 0; count < 100; count++)
                {
                    if (createdImportStreamArray[count][0] == idOfEl)
                    {
                        node.push({
                            predefinedStream: createdImportStreamArray[count][1],

                     //...Continued

 var flowChart = {};
 flowChart.elements =node;
 var flowChartJson = JSON.stringify(flowChart);
 $('#jsonOutput').val(flowChartJson);
}
```

The interface looks as shown below. When the <kbd>Load</kbd> button is clicked, according to the `loadFlowChart()` method as shown in the first piece of code, each element's is, class and top position needs to be alerted.

[image: Json output]

But am getting an error and this error is not even in any of the scripts that I've written but jquery helper scripts.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

[image: Error]

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in trying to loop through the node of the Json output and any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does this return? `var node = objFromJson.node;`

Comment: It gets the node array within the Json output which hosts the objects from which individual pieces of data needs to be drawn(As defined in the `saveFlowchart()` method

Comment: Does it contain any data?

Comment: Yes. It retrieves all the node related data from which each minuscule info needs to be grabbed from. This is according to my understanding. But if there is an alternative way to do the above. I'll be glad to know

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments this part is correct, but when one reads it it doesn't seem to be.

In the following function:

```
function loadFlowchart() {
    // Here you get the contents of the input field as text 
    var flowChartJson = $('#jsonOutput').val();
    // Here you parse it into a Javascript object
    var objFromJson = JSON.parse(flowChartJson);
    // Here you access the "node" attribute of that object, but if I look to the screenshot 
    // you provided there is no "node" attribute in the input field. If that's the case, 
    // then "node" is "undefined" and it would produce the error you indicate.
    var node = objFromJson.node;
    // you can verify by showing the full object on the console
    console.log(objFromJson);
    // The input field, as seen on the screenshot, would suggest you need to access the
    // "elements" attribute instead of "node".
    var node = objFromJson.elements;
    $.each(node, function (index, element) {
        var id = element.id;
        var classes = element.class;
        var positionTop = element.position.top
        alert("Id of element parsed: " + id + "\nclass: " + classes 
        + "\npositionTop: " + positionTop);
    });
}
```

Comment: This error indicates that there is no "elements" attribute in objFromJson. Do `console.log(objFromJson)` to examine the objFromJson object and check its attributes.